# How to use Regex Split in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I want to understand this line of code.

```
                    // Splitting Time
                    string time = Regex.Split(t, "scrollbars=yes")[1].Substring(4, 8);
                    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lets take the first row as an example

```
string time = Regex.Split(t, "scrollbars=yes")[1].Substring(4, 8);
```

Split method takes two arguments, first is the string which in this case is `t`
and the second parameter is the pattern we want to split by, in this case, `"scrollbars=yes"`, and return a `string[]` as a result

so let's say `t` is `hello scrollbars=yes world123457890` you will get `string[]` in the size of, the first place contains `"hello"` and the second  `"world123457890"`

Next is the `[1] operator, which means we take the string in the first place, in our example is the string`"world123457890"`

Next, we take the string we `"world123457890"` and we do a `substring` from index 4, and we take 8 characters

so the result in `time` string is `ld123457`

all other rows are more the less the same

you can read about `Regex.Split` [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8yttk7sy(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: so from what I understood from your answer is

Take this pattern "scrollbars=yes" [1] means take the first string after that which is world123457890. Now do a substring on this world123457890 and start the index from 1-4 (worl) 4 ends at L and then from L count till 8 characters "LD123457", is this correct?

Comment: @Patrick, yes, i wrote this at the answer, you start from character at the 4th index which  and you count 8 characters ahead, which is untill 7